# Calling User.all inside a Rails User model is only returning the current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to debug an issue in a Rails project where something was going wrong inside the User model.

Some binding.pry action led me to the realisation that when I call `User.all` from inside the user model, ActiveRecord is generating the following SQL;

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`provider` = 'google_oauth2' AND `users`.`uid` = '...'
```

The same happens when calling `self.class.all`.

At no stage have I asked this query to limit on provider or uid, there are no default scopes set up on the class either.

The only relevant thing *I think* could be that this is the devise setup for the user model;

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
       :omniauthable
```

### My Questions

- Why is this happening?
- Is this something I need to fix, or is there another way to achieve `User.all`

### Notes

- `User.all` isn't my actual call, but it is the simplest reduction of the problem

### Method

The method where this is being called is a public method on the class;

```
def create_slug
  if User.where(slug: name.parameterize).present?
    #Stuff happens here, but the User.where isn't bringing back what I would expect
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you paste your method where you are calling it?

Comment: Maybe there's some scope already used? Show your code.

Comment: @usmanali – I have copied the shell of the method into my main question, thanks.

Comment: @MarekLipka There are scopes on the method, but none are being called in my query.

Comment: @Toby what happens if you use `User.unscope`?

Comment: @MarekLipka - oh nice! `User.all.unscope(:where)` acts as expected.

Comment: You don't need `all`.  BTW I wonder why exactly this happens.

Comment: If `unscope` resolves your issue, so there is somewhere up your `create_slug` call an `around_filter` or something else calling `with_scope(...) do`... You have to find it :)